# Use attribute label from another website

Tags: product-attribute

Is there an easy way of copying an attribute label from one website and using it in another on Magento.

I have just set up a number of new websites in a multistore environment to allow for international sales and would like the attribute labels from the original store to be copied across into the new stores.

Thanks,

Hugh

Comment: Which magento version you used?

Comment: Magento 1.9.0.1